# Using Bazaar (BZR) on AFP or SMB mounted server not wroking

Tags: server-message-block, afp, bazaar

Has anyone been able to get BZR working on a mounted AFT or SMB mounted share?  I've tried both (The AFP volume is actually coming off an Xserver.) and neither work.  I have BZR 2.0.0 and am running it on a Mac with 10.5.  I keep getting an error like this

```
bzr: ERROR: Could not acquire lock "/Volumes/joeserver/Documents/bzr/remote_test/.bzr/checkout/dirstate": [Errno 45] Operation not supported
```

I googled around a bit but only found a fairly stale (2007) bug report on launchad.com (Bug #313625 to be specific.)  Any ideas?

Comment: Finally gave up on bazaar and used Mercurial instead.  It doesn't seem to mind working off a shared volume.